# tray icon doesn't close immediately on app.quit in electron

Tags: electron, destroy, trayicon

I am using electron tray in my application but when I quit the app ,the tray doesn't close immediately.Instead on hover, it closes immediately .Is there any solution that I can use to avoid this?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: When you quit your app do you press `Ctrl`+`C` in the terminal or do you call `app.quit()`? If its `Ctrl`+`C` then I don't think you can fix it but if it's `app.quit()` then my answer should work.

Comment: okay I got yyour point .Thanks Mike.Your solution should work in app.quit case..I was trying with ctrl +c so it didnt.

Comment: No problem :), if my answer was helpful please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try destroying the tray icon before the app quits like this:

```
app.on('before-quit', function (evt) {
    tray.destroy();
});
```

[`tray.destroy()` Docs.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/tray#traydestroy)

[`before-quit` Event docs.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-before-quit)